# Static extension functions not work in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want a static extension function.
I've created one, it does not work.
I've copied one from a tutorial, it works.

Why does the copied function work on my function does not?

This is the extension

```
extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {
  String toDbDate() {
    return DbService.dtFormat.format(this);
  }

  static DateTime parseDbDate(String dbDate) {
    return DbService.dtFormat.parse(dbDate);
  }
}

// extension from tutorial I followed works
extension ShapeBorderX on ShapeBorder {
  static ShapeBorder roundedRectangle(double radius) {
    return RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(radius),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is how I use it

```
  method() {
    DateTime.now().toDbDate();           // works
    DateTime.parseDbDate("2020-02-01");  // does not work
    ShapeBorderX.roundedRectangle(12.0); // works
  }
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what..

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "Static" extension methods means that the method is declared as a static method of the extension class but syntactic sugar allows it to be called as though it was an instance method on objects of the extended type. It is not currently possible in Dart to declare an extension static method (as in a method you can call on the extended type directly).

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I see it now.

I have to call the method on the **extension** not on the class it extends.

`DateTimeExtension.parseDbDate(...)` works fine.